# How to build an "Upgrade" or "Buy Premium" for app without being pushy

Tags: mobile

How do I get my users to upgrade in my app which has 4 screens 
1. menu, settings, list and note page. 
2. I don't want to be obnoxious neither pushy for them to upgrade
3. I hate ads so the only revenue source would be premium features

My solutions were
1. Show premium features/buttons but when they tap on it say - "Only for PRO members" 
2. Promote discount as popup
3. Give free 1 month membership automatically with a popup if the user is a regular user
4. have option to upgrade on the menu ALL THE TIME

I'm confused.

Comment: Take a look at Plex. It's a free app and service, but there are premium features built on top. Partly this is a psychological though, because a lot has to do with how your users feel about you and the app. If they like you and they feel like what they are getting is fair or more than fair, they'll be more willing to buy upgrades, regardless of the UI for buying it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use everything except the popup**

All of these options can be used together to create a non-pushy upgrade promotion.

- Make it obvious that some features are premium level by **disabling links and buttons**, and making it clear why the features are disabled either via some fixed 'Premium Only' text or a tooltip. This text or tooltip could also contain a link to the upgrade page.
- Have a prominent **link or button that lives in the menu**, so that when users are ready to upgrade they know where to look. This might link to a landing page with a full explanation of the benefits and relevant forms.
- Offer some sort of upgrade incentive. This can be whatever your profit margins allow for, and there are lots of flavors to choose from (that could be a different question)

The only thing that's pushy about your proposed methods is the popup option. Users universally dislike having to deal with popups.